# How do I change the SPARQL query using the sparql_views module?

Tags: views

I'm using the [SPARQL Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/sparql_views) to pull in data from the [DBLP](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/) endpoint, it's pulling data and displaying it in views based on the field mappings, the SPARQL query however is generated dynamically and I'm not able to modify it, any suggestions on how to directly enter a query would be great.